# Determine if "+" (plus) key in keydown is from the numpad?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to determine which key is pressed by the user.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
    $("#keyCode").html("Key Code: " + code);
});
```

My problem is that the code for +/= key is the same as the code for the numpad plus key. Both are 107. How can I tell which of these two keys were pressed?

Update

It looks like this problem is specific to Firefox. Chrome and IE give me codes of 107 and 187.

Comment: jQuery has already done the `keyCode/charCode/which` checks for you, so you can just use `var code = e.which`

Comment: Yep, `event.which` is the right way in jQuery.

Comment: Create a answer for that not just a comment! @ Esailja

Comment: @Hippo that's not really an answer though? It's just nitpicking on the code

Comment: What browser are you testing on? I've tried a test where the keycode is printed and the "numpad +" is 107 and the +/= is 187. I used this to test: http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

Comment: Quirksmode is a good reference for this.

Comment: event.which is giving me the same behavior. I have discovered this seems to be Firefox specific. Chrome and IE give different codes for each key 107 and 187

Comment: If I would have asked the question, this would be all I need. And I didn't know about this before. @ Esailija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work properly in Firefox was to use the keypress event and get the charCode. I also keep track of if the Shift key is held down.